# Automated Shapefile/Feature Class source credit from metadata in ArcGIS layout

Tags: arcgis-desktop, metadata, layouts, attribution

In ArcGIS (10.1), is there a way to automatically place the attribution (= source credits) of my data onto the map layout? The source credits are stored within the metadata (Item Description) and the shapefiles/feature classes are located within the folder structure.

The data within the folder structur is accessed by many users and not all of them know which attribution has to be used when they add the layer to their mxd.

Im thinking of the case of web mapping solutions, where one can specify that the source credits of visible layers are placed in the bottom left or right corner.

Any hints or ideas are welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Put a path statement to each layer in the map on the layout? Set up a Coded Domain so that attributes can only be selected from certain values? Create Feature Templates so that when creating new features you can preselect the appearance/attributes of the feature you're creating?

Comment: @ChrisW Would the interpretation "how can specific metadata field values be placed automatically in text boxes on a layout" make sense for you?

Comment: @whuber That's certainly another valid interpretation, especially if 'attribution' means source credits.

Comment: @whuber that's exactly what I'm looking for. I want to place metadata field values (= the layer's source credits) automatically on a layout whenever the shapefile/feature class is added to the map layout.

Comment: I'm not sure if dynamic text can pull info from metadata or not, but it might be something to explore. Otherwise I think you're looking at some sort of ArcObjects or possibly ArcPy solution, which is beyond my level.

Comment: was there any solution to the initial question above? Thanks!!